# Is <a href> causing forced distance?

Tags: html, xhtml

On my page there are 2 different ways to view a "map".

The first way just shows the map.
The second way contains links to each quarter of the map.

This is the second way whichs result is not looking as I want it to look.
Is this caused by the img wrapping `<a href="...">`?

Or what could be causing this distance?

And how could I fix this?
(Wihtout using CSS, as I'm currently not able to use CSS because fo personal reasons.)

```
<a href="http://www.straight-devel.com/test?Frame=12&amp;SqrXIndex=0&amp;SqrYIndex=0">
    <img src="/2000.png" title="12" alt="12"/>
</a><a href="http://www.straight-devel.com/test?Frame=12&amp;SqrXIndex=0&amp;SqrYIndex=1">
    <img src="/1001.png" title="1" alt="1"/>
</a><a href="http://www.straight-devel.com/test?Frame=12&amp;SqrXIndex=0&amp;SqrYIndex=2">
    <img src="/1100.png" title="1" alt="1"/>
</a><a href="http://www.straight-devel.com/test?Frame=12&amp;SqrXIndex=0&amp;SqrYIndex=3">
    <img src="/1111.png" title="2" alt="2"/>
</a><a href="http://www.straight-devel.com/test?Frame=12&amp;SqrXIndex=0&amp;SqrYIndex=4">
    <img src="/2200.png" title="14" alt="14"/>
</a>
<br/>
```

The result looks like this:

[Alot of unwanted space http://www.star-hole.com/pictures/incorrect.png](http://www.star-hole.com/pictures/incorrect.png)

This is the way without the links:

```
<img src="/2000.png" title="12" alt="12"/>
<img src="/1001.png" title="1" alt="1"/>
<img src="/1100.png" title="1" alt="1"/>
<img src="/1111.png" title="2" alt="2"/>
<img src="/2200.png" title="14" alt="14"/>
<br/>
```

And the resulting map looks the way I want the other map to look like too:

[Alot of unwanted space http://www.star-hole.com/pictures/correct.png](http://www.star-hole.com/pictures/correct.png)

Is there anyone whos able to help me?

**EDIT**

I should note, that the code snippets just are for the first row of the map.
As The way they generate the map doesn't change and each row is the same code (its dynamicly done in a C loop, so its 100% sure)

Comment: try to add css `a, img {margin: 0; padding: 0;}`

Comment: where and how? As I said, I currently don't know how to use CSS.

Comment: sorry to break it to you, but your "without" css strategy might not work. Browsers apply their own idea of "useful" CSS if none is defined, which could be the issue for you right now.

Comment: could not use css because of personal reason? sounds legit... anyway, add INLINE-STYLES instead. try removing margins, paddings etc. not only for a tags but also for its parents. --- edit: ahh you don't know.. you should have said that early on.

Comment: Without CSS, the result does *not* look like the first image in the question. Please provide sufficient data to actually reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the `head` tag add these style

```
<style type="text/css">
  a, img {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
</style>
```

Comment: The question said “Wihtout using CSS”, so why was this accepted? Besides, it does not actually remove all spacing if the code is as in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Hmm the horizontal spacing is curious. 
To elaborate on Ishank's answer.

Add the following in between the `<head> </head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

Open up a new document and save it in the same directory as your HTML file name it: **style.css**

Paste the following into the new document:

[Original Comment]
Perhaps try to remove all padding and margins which the browser applies by:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

I highly recommend you use Cascading Style-Sheets (CSS).
A good resource to start learning is here:
[WebPlatform.Org: CSS](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/tutorials)

Comment: and where to write this? Inside each `<a>`tag?

Comment: No. Between your `<head>` tags, and in the middle of `<style type="text/css"> {Paste here} </style>`

Comment: Thank you for your comment H. 
Zaibis, please see my edited answer on how to ideally use CSS. There's nothing wrong with using same-page CSS as H mentioned. Though I would love for you to learn CSS and store it all within a separate document.

Answer (score 1):

You could do an internal CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Your Page Title Goes Here!</title>
    <style>
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="http://www.straight-devel.com/test?Frame=12&amp;SqrXIndex=0&amp;SqrYIndex=0">
    <img src="/2000.png" title="12" alt="12"/>
</a><a href="http://www.straight-devel.com/test?Frame=12&amp;SqrXIndex=0&amp;SqrYIndex=1">
    <img src="/1001.png" title="1" alt="1"/>
</a><a href="http://www.straight-devel.com/test?Frame=12&amp;SqrXIndex=0&amp;SqrYIndex=2">
    <img src="/1100.png" title="1" alt="1"/>
</a><a href="http://www.straight-devel.com/test?Frame=12&amp;SqrXIndex=0&amp;SqrYIndex=3">
    <img src="/1111.png" title="2" alt="2"/>
</a><a href="http://www.straight-devel.com/test?Frame=12&amp;SqrXIndex=0&amp;SqrYIndex=4">
    <img src="/2200.png" title="14" alt="14"/>
</a>
<br/>
</body>
</html>
```